# Appbar scrolling view behavior

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I use Android X in my project. For some reason AS can't find @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior

```
 <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/home_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/alto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

My dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0'
```

Does someone know how to fix it or should I move back to supportLib?

Comment: This is an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061962/whats-alternative-to-appbarlayoutscrollingviewbehavior-in-androidx

Comment: Well, the link you sent did not same with the question you asked.